# Dup Blocker Custom Apex Handler

Tags: apex

Does anyone have experience with the DupBlocker's custom Apex handler? What are the methods and variables that should be exposed to make this work. The documentation we have stops at the point where this is being explained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting them directly through their portal if this is the case.

Comment: I've submitted a request for information. I just thought I'd pick the brains that are here as well. BTW, this is with their version 3.0.1 so there is also the possibility that this feature isn't fully implemented yet since it is new to 3.0.1.

Comment: That's a new feature in version 3, so I doubt anybody has experience with it. I'd also recommend contacting them directly.

Comment: I presume it's an installed, managed package? They would have an interface class (global) that you can view to determine available methods and objects for their hook functions.

Answer (score 1):

OK, CRM Fusion got back with us. It appears that it is a feature that is supposed to be in 3.0 but is not yet in the 3.0.1 beta release. Due to be out in beta in a month or so. No wonder we couldn't get it to work nor see any attempt to access our class.

Welcome to the bleeding edge.